# How do I pass arguments to django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I want to filter form fields querysets based on the user selected. Therefore, I want to pass user as argument to the form in order to filter fields querysets in the form's `__init__` method. When I pass any arguments to the form I get the following error.

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = TbUser
    form_class = TbPeopleEntranceRightForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = TbPeopleEntranceRightForm(user=self.object)
        context['form'] = form
        return context

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

how do I pass the argument correctly, and how I get it in the `__init__`  form method?

Update:

```
class TbPeopleEntranceRightForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(user)
        # Use `self.user` here or in some other methods.

__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

Comment: Please try my answer and let me know if it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't do it in `get_context_data`, it's made for something else.
Use `get_form_kwargs` instead:

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = TbUser
    form_class = TbPeopleEntranceRightForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["user"] = self.object
        return kwargs
```

And in your `forms.py`:

```
def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: your solution works, but when I print self.user, the form is initiated 2 times, the first time it prints the user, the second time the user is none. Why it behaves like this?

Comment: How many times are you creating an instance of your `FormClass` ?  this method is called when an object is created from a class @Brat

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the parameter to the form's `__init__` method:

```
class TbPeopleEntranceRightForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ...

    def __init__(self, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.user = user
        # Use `self.user` here or in some other methods.
```

Also, the correct way to then pass the `user` argument to the form is to override `get_form_kwargs` in the view, like [@MojixCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11487872/mojixcoder) showed.